# Data Frame Simplification

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have this data frame df that I'm able to manipulate with the following lines of code:

```
region = df.groupby('Company', as_index=False).agg({'NA':'sum', 'EU': 'sum', 'JP': 'sum'})

region_NA = df.nlargest(3, 'NA')
```

which yields the following data frame (the numbers are sales):

```
Company | NA  | EU  | JP
  CO_A  | 316 | 240 | 70
  CO_B  | 217 | 300 | 50
  CO_C  | 50  | 100 | 400
```

I could then use region_EU = df.nlargest(3, 'EU') and region_JP = df.nlargest(3, 'JP') to find the top companies that sold the most in EU and JP. But this is cumbersome because they each would return a separate data frame.

My problem is that these aren't quite the data frames I desire. I want to return the companies which sold the most in these 3 regions in a more organized manner. How do I get a data frame to look like the following:

```
Company | Region | Sales
  CO_A  |  NA    |  316
  CO_B  |  EU    |  300
  CO_C  |  JP    |  400
```

In my original data frame it is important to note that there is no explicit 'Region' column. Instead there are 3 columns NA, EU, and JP.

Comment: Remove `as_index=False` from your `groupby`. Then after the groupby you need `region.stack().nlargest(3)`

Answer (score 0):

Following operations you can do after groupby,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'company' :['CO_A','CO_B','CO_C'] ,'NA':  [316,217,50], 'EU':  [240,300,100] ,'JP':  [70,50,400]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['company'],df2['Region'] = df['company'],list(df.drop(['company'],axis=1).idxmax(axis=1))
df2['Sales'] = df.drop(['company'],axis=1).apply(lambda x: max(x), axis=1)
```

Outputs:

```
print(df)
  company   NA   EU   JP
0    CO_A  316  240   70
1    CO_B  217  300   50
2    CO_C   50  100  400

print(df2)
  company Region  Sales
0    CO_A     NA    316
1    CO_B     EU    300
2    CO_C     JP    400
```

Comment: But what about the company column? Writing df2['Company'] = df['Company'] would simply give a wrong solution.

Comment: @Alarcon_17 , I have updated answer and it gives output dataframe same as you have posted as a requirement. I do not think df2['Company'] = df['Company'] would make any mistake. Because df is the dataframe after groupby operation.